# The tf.case cannot run twice correctly

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I am using google colab as a tool to learn Stanford cs20 tensorflow course. I found a strange thing about tf.case.  Here is [the colab notebook](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Bw7iLXBJFk4b8ss5-yJrKGixiWEzYlco/view?usp=sharing)

The code is simple in that nodebook and run successfully. Then I changed the following line:

```
out_1b = tf.case({tf.less(x1, y1): lambda: tf.add(x1, y1), 
            tf.greater(x1, y1): lambda: tf.subtract(x1, y1)}, 
            default=lambda: tf.constant(0.0), exclusive=True)
```

I changed the *tf.constant(0.0)* to *tf.constant(0)*, it will throw error as the type doesn't match as expected. But after I changed it back to  *tf.constant(0.0)* and then it doesn't work with the following error:

```
 ValueError: Operation 'case_2/cond/Merge' has been marked as not fetchable.
```

I had to recreate a new session to make it works again. Can some explain the reason behind the situation?